# create CSV in a different name if file already exists

Tags: php, csv

i have been creating a CSV by using array of data, currently it returns an error if a CSV already exists in the same location.

therefore is there a possibility where i could let it create another in the same location.

example : if theres a csv called **report.csv** to create a new one with auto generated name like **report(1).csv**

code

```
$exportBaseDir = 'C:/Users/myflder';
$fileD = "report".csv";
$basePath = "$exportBaseDir/weeklyReport/$fileD";
$fp = fopen($basePath, 'w');
$header = array("XXX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX");
fputcsv($fp, $header, ',');
foreach ($tables as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields,',');
}
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: you need to check if the file already exist in the file path you are going to save the csv;
you can simple use the file_exist() function of php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

if (file_exist($basePath )) {

# do some processing to create a new file name
} else {
 # retain original file name
}

Comment: Also you can always add `time()` prefix to your file. In this case, the probability that the file names match will be very small.

Comment: yeah stpozer.. yeah i too was thinking of time as a unique variable

Comment: Also http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php will be very reliable:)

Answer (score 1):

working example finally.. thank you for your ideas

```
$exportBaseDir = 'C:/Users/myflder';
$fileD = "report".csv";
$basePath = "$exportBaseDir/weeklyReport/$fileD";
if(file_exists($basePath) == false){
$fp = fopen($basePath, 'w');
$header = array("XXX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX");
fputcsv($fp, $header, ',');
foreach ($tables as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields,',');
}
}
else{
    $time_start = time();
    $exportBaseDir = 'C:/Users/myflder';
    $fileD = "report"."#".$time_start.".csv";
    $basePath = "$exportBaseDir/weeklyReport/$fileD";
        $fp = fopen($basePath, 'w');
        $header = array("XXX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX");
        fputcsv($fp, $header, ',');
        foreach ($tables as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields,',');
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the well descriptive script

Comment: Thanks you no worries!! :)